# How to know total number of Frame in a file with cv2 in python

Tags: python, opencv, video, frame, frame-rate

How to know total number of Frame in a file ( .avi) through Python using open cv module.

If possible what all the information (resolution, fps,duration,etc)  we can get of a video file through this.

Answer (score 187):

With a newer OpenCV version (I use 3.1.0) it works like this:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print( length )
```

And similar for other video properties `cv2.CAP_PROP_*`

Comment: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT'

Comment: Are you sure, you're using OpenCV version 3+? I've just tested with version 3.3.1 and still works.

Comment: Any idea what is the complexity of the `cap.get()` ?

Comment: I tested it just now, for me it's working also with .avi video files. Right now I'm using version 4.0.1-dev on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Are you sure, your video file is not broken?

Comment: Or as some other commenters here hinted on it, it depends what is in your avi container... Apparently, sometimes it's just not available - you could try using some different encoder for your video file.

Answer (score 56):

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fn)

if not cap.isOpened(): 
    print("could not open :",fn)
    return
    
length = int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
width  = int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps    = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get) for more info.

also, all of it with a grain of salt, not all those props are mandatory, some might not be available with your capture / video codec

Comment: CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT is giving 0 values , Here is the code              import cv2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

filename= "test.avi"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
print 'fps='+str(fps)
Frames = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
print 'Frames='+str(Frames)                                       Can you tell where i am doing wrong.

Comment: you're probably not doing anything wrong. again, avi is just a container, there might be *anything* in it, and some codecs just don't support querying certain properties.

Comment: Hi berak, Sorry for the late replay, can you please give me little bit more hint on this.

Answer (score 23):

There are two methods to determine the number of frames in a video file

- Method #1: Utilize built-in OpenCV properties to access video file meta information 
  which is **fast and efficient but inaccurate**
- Method #2: Manually loop over each frame in the video file with a counter which is **slow and inefficient but accurate**

Method #1 is fast and relys on OpenCV's [video property functionality](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d) which almost instantaneously determines the number of frames in a video file. However, there is an accuracy trade-off since it is dependent on your OpenCV and video codec versions. On the otherhand, manually counting each frame will be 100% accurate although it will be significantly slower. Here's a function that attempts to perform Method #1 by default, if it fails, it will automatically utilize method #2

```
def frame_count(video_path, manual=False):
    def manual_count(handler):
        frames = 0
        while True:
            status, frame = handler.read()
            if not status:
                break
            frames += 1
        return frames 

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    # Slow, inefficient but 100% accurate method 
    if manual:
        frames = manual_count(cap)
    # Fast, efficient but inaccurate method
    else:
        try:
            frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        except:
            frames = manual_count(cap)
    cap.release()
    return frames
```

---

Benchmarks

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    import cv2

    start = timeit.default_timer()
    print('frames:', frame_count('fedex.mp4', manual=False))
    print(timeit.default_timer() - start, '(s)')

    start = timeit.default_timer()
    print('frames:', frame_count('fedex.mp4', manual=True))
    print(timeit.default_timer() - start, '(s)')
```

Method #1 results

```
frames: 3671
0.018054921 (s)
```

Method #2 results

```
frames: 3521
9.447095287 (s)
```

Note the two methods differ by 150 frames and *Method #2 is significantly slower than Method #1*. Therefore if you need speed but willing to sacrifice accuracy, use Method #1. In situations where you're fine with a delay but need the exact number of frames, use Method #2

Comment: which one would be the real frame count of my video, asking because medainfo is giving a 3rd valur different from the 2 you describe

Answer (score 17):

Here is how it works with Python 3.6.5 (on Anaconda) and OpenCV 3.4.2.
[Note]: You need to drop the "CV_" from the "CV_CAP_PROP_xx" for any property as given on the official OpenCV [website](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html).

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
property_id = int(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) 
length = int(cv2.VideoCapture.get(cap, property_id))
print( length )
```

Comment: This is great! You can also retrieve using `length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))`

Answer (score 6):

Another solution that doesn't depend on the sometimes buggy `CV_CAP_PROP` getters is to traverse your whole video file in a loop

- Increase a **frame counter** variable every time a valid frame is encountered and stop when an invalid one comes (end of the video file).
- Gathering information about the **resolution** is trickier because some codecs support variable resolution (similar to VBR in audio files where the bitrate is not a constant but instead covers some predefined range).

  - **constant resolution** - you need only the first frame to determine the resolution of the whole video file in this case so traversing the full video is not required
  - **variable resolution** - you need to get the resolution of every single frame (width and height) and calculate an average to get the average resolution of the video
- **FPS** can be calculated however here you have the same problem as with the resolution - constant (CFR) vs variable (VFR). This is more of a mutli-threading problem omho. Personally I would use a frame counter, which increased after each valid frame while at an interval of 1 second a timer (running in a background thread) would trigger saving the current counter's value and then resetting it. You can store the values in a list in order to calculate the average/constant frame rate at the end when you will also know the total number of frames the video has.

The disadvantage of this rather simplistic way of doing things is that you have to traverse the whole file, which - in case it's several hours long - will definitely be noticeable by the user. In this case you can be smart about it and do that in a background process while letting the user do something else while your application is gathering this information about the loaded video file.

The advantage is that no matter what video file you have as long as OpenCV can read from it you will get quite accurate results unlike the `CV_CAP_PROP` which may or may not work as you expect it to.