# Python and OpenCV - getting the duration time of a video at certain points

Tags: python, opencv, video

Let say I have made a program to detect a green ball in a video. Whenever there is a green ball detected, I want to print out the duration of video at the time the green ball is detected. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359361/1150303), you will find a solution to determine the frames per second.

so you'd want to use:

```
fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

and count the number of frames you're at. Then you can compute the video time with

```
videotime = current_frame_number / fps.
```

EDIT:

@Miki suggested to use `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` which should result in the same time (in [ms])

Corrected my typo as pointed out by @Swiper-CCCVI

Comment: wouldn't be easier to use `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` (_Current position of the video file in milliseconds_)?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the inverted measure of the video time?

Shouldn't it actually be current_frame_number / fps instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply measure a certain position in the video in milliseconds using

`time_milli = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)`

and then divide `time_milli` by 1000 to get the time in seconds.